# decorating a class function with a callable instance

Tags: python, class, decorator

I'm trying to decorate a function by replacing it with a instance of a callable class:

```
class FunctionFaker( object ):
    def __init__( self, f ):
        self.f= f
    def empty_function( self ):
        pass
    def __call__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        self.f( *args, **kwargs)

def fakefunction( f ):
    '''a decorator that transforms a function into a FunctionFaker'''
    return FunctionFaker(f)

@fakefunction
def dosomething():
    pass

dosomething.empty_function()
dosomething()
```

This works as expected.

However, as soon as I try to decorate a class method:

```
class Test( object ):
    @fakefunction
    def dosomething(self):
        pass

t=Test()
t.dosomething.empty_function()
t.dosomething()
```

I get a `TypeError: dosomething() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`.

Now, I think [I can answer the why](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods):

> To support method calls, functions include the `__get__()` method for binding methods during attribute access. This means that all functions are non-data descriptors which return bound or unbound methods depending whether they are invoked from an object or a class.

So, FunctionFaker, not being a function, doesn't have the said descriptor, thus not mangling the arguments.

How can I implement a callable class that is able to replace a instance method?

Comment: I just realized I can simply implement `__get__` and return a `types.MethodType`, but I don't really understand how doing so still enables you to call `empty_function`. Does it simply become an attribute of the `MethodType` instance? And is this a sane thing to do?

Comment: The signature is `types.MethodType(callable, instance, class)`, and you can pass any sort of callable, including an instance of a class that has a `__call__` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just realized I can simply implement `__get__` and return a `types.MethodType`, but I don't really understand how doing so still enables you to call empty_function.

It's because `MethodType` has a `__getattribute__` method that delegates unknown attributes to its `im_func`:

```
>>> t.dosomething
<bound method Test.? of <__main__.Test object at 0x107639550>>
>>> 'empty_function' in dir(t.dosomething)
False
>>> t.dosomething.__getattribute__
<method-wrapper '__getattribute__' of instancemethod object at 0x109583aa0>
>>> t.dosomething.__getattribute__('empty_function')
<bound method FunctionFaker.empty_function of <__main__.FunctionFaker object at 0x1095f2510>>
```

Of course in CPython, the C API doesn't exactly mirror the Python-level distinction between `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__`, so the way it's *really* implemented is with a custom [`getattro`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getattro) slot. You can read the details [in the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/classobject.c#l2298).

> Does it simply become an attribute of the `MethodType` instance?

Yes, but only dynamically, by giving you the attribute of the underlying callable.

I don't think they specifically intended to enable class instances substituting for functions with method descriptors of their own. But this support is needed for even simple cases of attaching attributes to methods. For example, with a standalone function, you can use a function attribute for, e.g., a memoization cache, or lazy-initialize-on-first-call setup. If `MethodType` didn't delegate attribute access to its `im_func` object, moving such a function into a class would break it, and the developer wouldn't be able to fix it unless he knew how descriptors worked and rewrote the method in an ugly way.

In fact, up to 2.3, methods didn't even have a `__dict__`; as you can see from [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.3/Objects/classobject.c#l2143), *all* attributes except for the C slots were delegated to `im_func` (by effectively duplicating the normal machinery to delegate everything to `im_func` but wrap errors). There was some debate about this, which you could probably find by searching the python-dev archives for a post by Christian Tismer in the pre-2.4 period with a relevant-looking subject (it may be [this thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-November/040301.html), but I didn't read the whole thing…). From 2.4 on, methods now do the normal lookup mechanism (except for the special case of `__doc__`), and only delegate to `im_func` if it fails.

> And is this a sane thing to do?

It's a little strange, and it *might* be simpler to add the `empty_function` attribute to the function object, instead of wrapping it in a class… but I don't think it's too unreasonable. (I assume you're asking about your code, not about how `MethodType` and descriptors are implemented.)

Comment: Amazing. Does `MethodType` implementing `__getattribute__` somehow mean python developers anticipated this very need? Or is there other reason to? The docs on MethodType are pretty sparse, is there any reference for this?

Comment: OK, I answered the first half of your comment in the edited answer. For the second half… no, there's really no reference but reading the source and/or reverse engineering. (The descriptor HOWTO you linked just points to the same source in `classobject.c` that I linked for details.) There are a handful of places like that in Python; they're gradually being cleaned up as the developers of PyPy and other implementations raise them, but this one is still undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  You want your class to also be a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__):

```
import types

class FunctionFaker( object ):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f= f

    def empty_function(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.empty_function()
        self.f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        # see https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods
        return types.MethodType(self, instance, cls)

@FunctionFaker
def foo(arg1):
  print "in foo", arg1

class Bar(object):
  @FunctionFaker
  def bar(self, arg1):
    print "in bar", self, arg1

foo('hello')  # in foo hello
Bar().bar('world')  # in bar <__main__.Bar object at 0x7fc50b90fb10> world
Bar().bar.empty_function()
```

Now, if your decorator is bound to a class, it behaves like a descriptor (binding the proper instance to `self` in the decorated function), and if it isn't bound to a class, it behaves as a normal decorator.  Neat.

Comment: No, this won't actually work; if he returns a `partial` instead of a `MethodType`, `empty_function` will raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @abarnert -- I'm not exactly sure where OP is calling empty_function from, but it seems to work in my tests . . .

Comment: He's already creating a descriptor that returns a `types.MethodType`, exactly as a normal function would, exactly as the docs explicitly recommend. Because `MethodType` has a delegating `__getattribute__`, `t.dosomething.empty_function()` works. With your change, `t.dosomething` is now a `partial`, so `t.dosomething.empty_function()` will raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @abanert spot on. But at this point, I really was wondering if this would work

Comment: @abarnert -- Ahh, now I see what OP wanted.  I didn't realize that the goal was to add an attribute to the function.  And thanks for the "as the docs explicitly recommend".  I'd not remembered that in the descriptor docs -- It's a shame that the `types` docs don't say more about the signatures of the various types and what they do...

Comment: @mgilson: I didn't remember it either, but he linked to it in the question. (And I agree with you about the `types` docs. Even the basic stuff that's available in the docstrings at runtime isn't in the web docs, and that's one of the few places in Python where that isn't true.)